# Jenkins Python Interpreter path : whitespaces are not allowed in Python interpreter's path

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins

I want to configure python on jenkins and for that I have used shinningpanda plugin on jenkins.
When I give path of python interpreter i.e "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32" and  run my job it gives me an error 
*"FATAL: whitespaces are not allowed in Python interpreter's path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32"*

I tried putting in double quotes, single quote, '\' but didnt work.

Can anyone help me with it ?

Comment: Check out the end of [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/53), are you using latest `pip` and `virtualenv`?

Comment: Yes, I verified the versions. I am using latest versions. Thanks for posting the link but but I had gone through the link before posting the question.

Comment: No solution for the question, but I would probably just install python on a path without whitespaces, i.e. `C:\Python37-32` for your case. Looks like a big hassle to find out whats wrong. Edit: On the plugin page there is following changelog entry: `Make the build fail if there a some whitespace characters in PYTHONHOME (see. https://bugs.launchpad.net/virtualenv/+bug/241581).` So it seems it's advised to not have whitespaces in the python home.